# JSP Custom tag enforce Collection type

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am creating a custom `JSP` tag. I am including a `java.util.Collection` as an attribute like so:

```
<%@ attribute name="elements" type="java.util.Collection" required="true" %>
```

My question is, is there a way to enforce what the type of the Collection is?

So suppose I have an interface called `JSPSelect`, I would want to do something like this

```
<%@ attribute name="elements" type="java.util.Collection<JSPSelect>" required="true" %>
```

Is this possible?

If I attempt to do the above, it creates an unknown tag error.

Thanks